# need some films for knowing how can I use MySQL?

Tags: java, database

I am beginner in java and I don't know how can I use database and MySQL??and how can I write a code with data base:((

Comment: http://www.developer.com/article.php/3417381#Discussion%20and%20Sample%20Programs http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html#TOC_1

Comment: Films - ugh!!!  Am I old fashioned, or has everyone gotten too lazy to read any more?

Comment: @Stephen: Probably both! :-D I agree though; Wanting to see films is not a good sign of the sort of do-it-yourself curious mentality a developer needs.

Comment: This might be of help, Johanna: http://tinyurl.com/yj3l5sl

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to read the following tutorials:

- [Connecting to a MySQL Database in NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/60/ide/mysql.html)
- [Making a simple MySQL client in NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/articles/mysql-client.html)
- [Creating a Simple Web Application in NetBeans IDE Using MySQL](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/55/mysql-webapp.html)

They will help you to get started with Java, JDBC, MySQL and NetBeans. Good material for beginners.